# How to make label and input type text box in a single line using span classes for phone mode with twitter bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have done like this..

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        Username:
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Kindly suggest any ideas to do this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it's working as you wish.

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="Username">Username</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <input required type="text" name="Username" id="Username" class="input-xlarge">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```